# Why I can't format Python code in VScode?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, format

In MacOS, I couldn't find the right way to format my python code in VScode, although I watched many videos on youtube ("prettie now" or sth like this: I used to try but it failed)
Pls help me, many thanks!

Comment: What shortcut do you use to format your Python code in VS Code on Windows?

Comment: Oh, sorry to bother everyone, I remove my app-vscode and download again. So, I install prettie now, then command-S that file and it's really formated !